# Calculating average for each student

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following tables:

**-- table student**

```
create table Student(
num int primary key identity,
firstName varchar(30) not null,
lastName varchar(30)
)
```

**-- table module**

```
create table Module(
code int primary key identity,
name varchar(30) not null,
coefficient int not null)
```

**-- table notation**

```
create table Notation(
stud int references student,
Mod int references Module,
DateExam datetime default getdate(),
Note float check (Note between 0 and 20)
primary key(stud , Mod ))
```

What I want is to display student names, the student num and averages, ranked from best to worst.

**Update:**

average = sum (ni*ci)/ sum (ci); c: coefficient. n: note

Comment: Average of what?

Comment: Their numbers?, what numbers?

Comment: I don't think you want to use NOTE as a float.  Decimal(x,y)  would likely be better (depending on how many decimals you want to track.)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would eliminate assumptions

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Lamak serial number

Comment: @Frank version 2008

Comment: @user7233170 Where do you mention a Serial number column anywhere in the schema you have provided? Do you mean the num column on the Student table?

Comment: @Bridge yes you are right

Comment: @user7233170 Edited your question to clarify that, to save potential answerers digging around in the comments section!

Answer (score 2):

This gets both the note for each module for each student, and their average across all modules

```
select s1.FirstName, s1.LastName, m2.name as module_name, n3.Note, x1.av_note
from student s1
left join notation n3
  on n3.stud = s1.num
left join module m2
  on m2.code = n3.mod
left join
(
select stud, avg(note) as av_note
from notation
group by stud
) x1
  on s1.num = x1.stud
order by av_note, lastname desc
```

Comment: This would exclude all students without notes.  shouldn't we keep those; but otherwise good for db's w/o window functions! :P

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you need module. and this assumes note is the field you want to average.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Note, avg(note) over (partition by s.Num) AvgNote
FROM Student S
LEFT JOIN Notation N
 on S.Num = N.Stud
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, S.Num
ORDER BY as AvgNote Desc
```

Also, float as a data type when dealing with grades is a bad idea.  Float is imprecise by design to support a smaller datastorage footprint.  This doesn't matter when you're dealing with scientific notation and precision isn't necessary, but in this case I think decimal would be a better choice.

Comment: They are powerful.  I'm not sure what coefficient is on Module so  maybe we do need it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
select tab.num,tab.firstName, sum(noteMultiCoef)/sum(coefficient) as average from
    (select st.num,st.firstName, coefficient, note*coefficient as noteMultiCoef
    from notation nt, student st, Module md
    where st.num= nt.stud
    and nt.code = md.mod) tab
    group by tab.num, tab.firstName
    order by average desc
```